# How to write a stored procedure that copy data from one database to another

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Am having two server Production & development in which two different tables having different column names.So I want to write stored procedure that copy data from server test to demo.

Ex:
Two server Test and Demo having table name ABC and XYZ respectively

ABC table column name [DateTime,Months,Connection]
XYZ table column name [TimeDate,Total MOnths,Type of connection]

Any help would be appreciated

Thankyou,

Comment: why not a script? copying data between serves is an operational task, not a business/app task.

Comment: but I have to call that stored procedure in a web service

Comment: why do you *have to*? just have the web service call a shell script instead of a stored proc.

Comment: but I want to write stored procedure can any one please tell me how to write the above query.

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO 
          Test2
                (
                  CustomerId,
                  UserID, 
                  TestName,
                  Instructions,
                  Duration,
                  StartDateTime,
                  EndDateTime,


                )
SELECT 
     CustomerId,
      UserId, 
      TestName, 
      Instructions,
      Duration,
      StartDateTime,
      EndDateTime,

FROM 
    Test1 
WHERE 
    TestId = @CopiengId

SET @Id = @@IDENTITY
```